# How do I optimize this spark SQL join query?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, optimization

I want help with given spark SQL queries and get results in an optimized manner.
Below is an analogic schema

```
Table 1 - Players
player_number - INT
team_id - bigint (indexed)

Table 2 - Team
team_id - bigInt (indexed)
team_size - INT
```

I want to find all the team_ids where Team.number_of_players != Players.count(player_numer) group by team_ids.

I am running the below SQL query in spark but it's very slow for a bigger dataset and need some pointers for query optimization.

```
select id as teamId , teamSize from teams
  left outer join (select teamId, count(1) as size from players group by teamId) as players 
    on (teams.id= players.teamId) where players.size != teams.teamSize;
```

The table players can be quite huge. There can be as many as 10M players in a team. The table players is partitioned by team_id so the above query can run by itself on single partition.

Needs help speeding up this query.

Comment: In my experience, the way you have written the query is already the best for spark SQL - the only speed improvements I can see will probably come from data partitioning, join configuration, etc. Did you look at the event timeline to see if its bottlenecked? verify theres no skew? I assume these are all merge joins because of the size yes?

Comment: This link might give you a few ideas regarding configuration options https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-sql-performance-tuning-configurations/

Comment: For one, "left outer" can be changed to "inner" join because of your WHERE condition.

Comment: @mazaneicha there might be a case when all rows for players might be missing and only data is present in teams. Thus using left outer join to identify that issue